# Typo3 condition like with percent sign

Tags: symfony, typo3, expression, typo3-9.x

In my current Typo3 project i need to react on the cookies settings in typoscript.
My condition currently looks like:

```
[like(request.getCookieParams()['klaro'],'*gm%22%3Atrue*')]
page.includeJSFooter{
    10 = https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx
}
[END]
```

This fails every time. When i change it to a normal string like "true" / "false" it become true when this cookie contains this. As soon as i typ a % in the condition, it fails. Is this a unknown bug?
Have someone a other idea to check the cookie string?
Typo3 version is 11.5

Comment: Looks like the value includes url-encoded signs (%22 = `"`, %3A = `:`), so the string would translate to `*gm":true*`. This looks like having been copied from json but incomplete, as the starting `"` is missing. I don't know exactly how this is parsed but it's very likely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since TypoScript conditions are based on Symfony thus making use of regular expressions, you may not use plain `%` characters or notations that make use of those chracters, since they will be treated as delimiters:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#like

https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: and how can i use a ````%```` in the like condition?

Comment: You could try to use a chracter class to achieve that
https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php

Still it might be better to change the way you check for that value, since the actual value you want to get is "true" so you need to find out, how to get rid or how to access the array key you've got in your original pattern.